# How to apply CNOT with control qubits in first register and target qubit in second register

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

I would like to know how to mathematically describe the states of the qubits in both registers in the following circuit:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  You've generated a gate such that if $q0$ and $q1$ are both 1, then $q0'$ is inverted.  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, I'm trying to implement my own quantum computing simulation and I'm stuck at implementing multi-qubit gates when they are placed in different registers. I think I have to create the tensor product of both registers first and than apply my gates (like cx above). When reading single qubits I have to consider from which register it is to interpret the value of the corresponding bit correctly.

Comment: As far as the quantum computer is concerned, you've got a 5-qubit computer.  Your state vector is a 32-element vector, and your operators are 32x32 element matrices.  Registers are a convenience for the programmer, but don't mean anything to the computer.